# Jquery Colorbox breaks when css loaded in body, is a fix possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox, yepnope

Currently I have a fairly complex javascript project and 99% of resources are loaded via yepnope (this includes *.css, *.js). Now after reading this:

http://groups.google.com/group/colorbox/browse_thread/thread/850765cf0d64602a

It appears that Colorbox does some self configuring when the page loads, and it is required to be put within the head of the document so it is loaded before the page. Now I know this is the issue and this would be a simple fix, however I was wondering if there is a way to load it in the body and tell it to configure itself when *I* tell it to, not when the page loads?

If not, its not the end of the world, but thought I would ask the question anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and it is required to be put within the head of the document so it is loaded before the page

This is not true, put the script anywhere you want.  The CSS does need to be loaded though before you execute the script, because it depends on the styles in it.

Comment: To my knowledge the css is being loaded before the script (dont have the source to hand). If this is the case I will give you the answer and many thanks :)

Comment: Many thanks :) On a couple of pages it was being loaded after the script so have moved it around.